# $slice element from array inside another array

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What i want is to slice an array inside an array and return ONLY the queried array element. But i get instead every element from the first array.

I have this example input

```
[
  {
    "name": "admin",
    "datasets": [
      {
        "name": "test",
        "datapoints": [
          1,
          6,
          4,
          3,
          8,
          5,
          3
        ],
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "619288f16733758444a28728"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "more datasets",
        "datapoints": [
          1,
          2,
          3,
          4,
          5,
          6,
          7,
          8
        ],
        "_id": {
          "$oid": "619289086733758444a2872a"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

I have tried it with

```
db.collection.find({
  name: "admin",
  "datasets.name": "test"
},
{
  "datasets.datapoints": {
    $slice: [
      0,
      3
    ]
  }
})
```

The problem here is that i get every item of datasets

```
[
  {
    "_id": ObjectId("5a934e000102030405000000"),
    "datasets": [
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("619288f16733758444a28728"),
        "datapoints": [
          1,
          6,
          4
        ],
        "name": "test"
      },
      {
        "_id": ObjectId("619289086733758444a2872a"),
        "datapoints": [
          1,
          2,
          3
        ],
        "name": "more datasets"
      }
    ],
    "name": "admin"
  }
]
```

But i just need the 1

Result should just be:

```
{ datapoints: [1, 6, 4, 3] }
```

Answer (score 0):

Query

- map the datasets
- if `name :"test"` take the slice of the first 4 members
- else null
- filter to remove the null, so it remains only the "test" and with first 4 members
- result is array of arrays, because we might have many "test" members, if you are sure it will be always max 1 take the first member with `$first` or `$arrayElemAt`

*on find criteria if you have too many admins, you can add also "datasets.name": "test" if you have index on "datasets.name" it can help.

[PlayMongo](https://cmql.org/playmongo/?q=6233d181f7e3c64c6511e144)

```js
aggregate(
[{"$match": {"name": {"$eq": "admin"}}},
  {"$set": 
    {"datasets": 
      {"$map": 
        {"input": "$datasets",
          "in": 
          {"$cond": 
            [{"$eq": ["$$this.name", "test"]},
              {"datapoints": {"$slice": ["$$this.datapoints", 0, 4]},
                "_id": "$$this._id",
                "name": "$$this.name"},
              null]}}}}},
  {"$project": 
    {"_id": 0,
      "datasets": 
      {"$filter": 
        {"input": "$datasets", "cond": {"$ne": ["$$this", null]}}}}}])
```

Comment: 1 thing is missing the `_id` of the dataset "_id": ObjectId("619288f16733758444a28728"),

Comment: i updated the answer, i added also the `name` so you have all info you can remove it from code `"name": "$$this.name"`